# Facebook share via app loads two popups

Tags: facebook, feed

The problem can be watched here
http://antipinagroup.com/collections/sac-de-voyage

On sharing via fb app ui loads two popups — feed dialogue and blank page.
Can't get the problem. Any ideas why it happens and how to resolve it?

The code for forming

```
    objFB = {
method: 'feed',
link: document.location.href,
picture: fullPathImage + numimg +".jpg",
name: dataBl.title,
caption: dataBl.title,
description: dataBl['text description']};

_share = _share.replace(/href="javascript:;"/g,  'onclick="postToFeed(); return false;"' );                 
    $( "." + mainBlockClass + " #overlay_" +  mainBlockClass ).html( _share );
    break;}}); 

    (function(d){FB.init({appId: "151107748411463", status: true, cookie: true});}(document));
    function postToFeed() { function callback(response) { /*console.log(response);*/ }FB.ui(objFB, callback);}
```

Answer (score 0):

All I’m getting when I’m trying you FB share is

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.

 API Error Code: 1
 API Error Description: An unknown error occurred
 Error Message: kError 1349040: Invalid App ID: The provided app ID is invalid.
```

I added [`&show_error=true` at the end of the feed dialog URL](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?link=http://antipinagroup.com/collections/sac-de-voyage&picture=http://ruki-studio.ru/an2/images/cat/sacdevoyage/full/1.jpg&name=TRAVEL%20BAGS&caption=TRAVEL%20BAGS&description=Calfskin,%20Textile%20lining,%20Dual%20zip%20closure,%20Internal%20zip%20pocket,%20Double%20handle&e2e=%7B%7D&app_id=151107748411463&locale=en_GB&sdk=joey&display=popup&next=http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=25#cb=f4c2cd14091f28&origin=http%253A%252F%252Fantipinagroup.com%252Ff473d7c3a2b36c&domain=antipinagroup.com&relation=opener&frame=f4da7de0d3f158&result=%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522&show_error=true) your page creates as you can see, which is always (OK, make that most of the times) helpful to find errors with FB dialogs.

So first of all check your app id in your code.

Comment: Thanks, CBroe.
Strange. The App ID is right. Added redirect_uri. Now it works.
Sad but I thought earlier that the blank page is formed because of the missed redirect_uri, but it's not.